# error when I filter select statement by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I received a script from a work colleague to run when checking batches however the script works on his laptop but as soon as I run it on my device I get and error.
I don't know if it could be permissions since that's the only difference between our setups.

the script is to select certain columns convert date format with to_char for specific batch name and then filter for specific date time.
here is the sample code:

```
select batch_name, NO_OF_ITEMS, NUMBER_OF_ERRORS, to_char(RUN_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') EXECUTION_START, to_char(RUN_END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') EXECUTION_END,
to_char(START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') START_DATE, to_char(END_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') END_DATE, NOTES from bat_log
where BATCH_NAME in (
'SJ63R_03'
) 
and RUN_START_DATE between '04-Aug-2020 07:00' AND '05-Aug-2020 07:00'
order by run_start_date desc;
```

error I get:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

when I remove the time `07:00` from `RUN_START_DATE between '04-Aug-2020 07:00' AND '05-Aug-2020 07:00'` the script runs perfectly but obviously doesn't filter for the time frame.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Use to_char(RUN_START_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') in where clause as well.

Comment: that seem to have worked somewhat. I now receive results from all the months matching the day and time. not sure why the months are not filtering to only AUG

Comment: Are you sure that data exists in the table for 4th aug 7 AM ? Check it manually.

Comment: I would recommend instead using `to_date()` around each of your two filter dates. The format mask is still the same.

Comment: Dates and strings, two different things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate a bit your scenario

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 date , c2 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( to_date('01/08/2020 11:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , to_date('01/08/2020 17:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ( to_date('01/09/2020 11:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , to_date('01/09/2020 17:00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

C1        C2
--------- ---------
01-AUG-20 01-AUG-20
01-SEP-20 01-SEP-20

SQL> select c1 , c2 from t where to_char(c1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') between '02-AUG-2020 08:00' and '02-SEP-2020 08:00' ;

no rows selected

SQL> select c1 , c2 , to_char(c1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') as result from t ;

C1        C2        RESULT
--------- --------- --------------------------
01-AUG-20 01-AUG-20 01-AUG-2020 11:00
01-SEP-20 01-SEP-20 01-SEP-2020 11:00

SQL> select c1 , c2 from t where to_char(c1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') between to_date('02-AUG-2020 08:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
  2  and to_date('02-SEP-2020 08:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') ;
select c1 , c2 from t where to_char(c1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') between to_date('02-AUG-2020 08:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
                            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string


SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI' ;

Session altered.

SQL> select c1 , c2 from t where c1 between to_date('02-AUG-2020 08:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
and to_date('02-SEP-2020 08:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') ;  2

C1                C2
----------------- -----------------
01-SEP-2020 11:00 01-SEP-2020 17:00

SQL>
```

If the original fields are dates, you might change your NLS date settings to make it work, as well as applying to_date to the strings you want to compare as dates

**Update**

I remove the to_char to avoid an implicit conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed scenario and feedback, i will try editing the script with to_date tommorow and give feedback.

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez- perhaps I'm missing something in the point you are trying to make, but your last example ('where to_char(c1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') between to_date('02-AUG-2020 08:00") you come off comparing a string (to_char) to a date (to_date), forcing again the implicit conversion.  Also comparing as strings won't give the correct collating sequence  for comparing dates.

Comment: @EdStevens, you are right, I should have avoided the implicit conversion. I was trying to make a reproducible case.

Comment: Thanks changing the comparing strings to to_date worked

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something is different between your two setups.  It is the value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Your query is depending on an implicit TO_DATE() to convert the *strings* '04-Aug-2020 07:00' AND '05-Aug-2020 07:00' from strings to DATE, which is an internal, binary data type.  Since you are relying on implicit conversion, you are also relying on the underlying value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT to match the strings you are supplying.  This is why I always, always, always use to_date() and include the proper format mask:

```
RUN_START_DATE between to_date('04-Aug-2020 07:00','dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('05-Aug-2020 07:00','dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

For more background, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: Thanks for feedback, im going to try this tommorow and let you know, this does make sense.